# ComboBox SelectedItem change notification not always working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, selecteditem

I have a really baffling problem. I have an application that works just fine on most platforms, but does not work on a particular machine. We have even tested this application on the same type of machine as the one that fails and it works just fine. It is just one particular machine.

Here is the problem: The property bound to the SelectedItem attribute of a ComboBox does not change when a new item is selected in the GUI.

I want to emphasize that every machine we test this on works. It is only one machine that fails (unfortunately, it is in the hands of a customer!).

The binding is

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="4"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Width="160"
          Height="28"
          Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"
          FontSize="18"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
          ItemsSource="{Binding VM.Names}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding VM.CurrentName}" />
```

The relevant view model code is

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Names
{
    set
    {
        m_names = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Names");
    }
    get { return m_names; }
}

public string CurrentName
{
    set
    {
        m_currentName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentName");
         // Set back end cfg
        UpdateConfiguration(CurrentName);

        // Clear everything in UI
        ResetAll();
    }
    get { return m_currentName; }
}

private ObservableCollection<string> m_names;
private string m_currentName;

private void UpdateConfiguration(string name)
{
    if (string.Equals(name, "John", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        Config.LastName = "Doe";
    }
    else
    {
        Config.LastName = "Smith";
    }

    // Configure back end
    BackEnd.Instance.Reconfigure();
}
```

(Forgive the UpdateConfiguration() function. I modified it but left it as intact as possible without giving away anything company sensitive)

The two obvious symptoms we observe on the machine that fails are:
1) The current value of Name is not saved to a file on exit. The value is saved correctly on all other machines.
2) The ResetAll() function is not called.

I would appreciate any insight anyone has as to why this would be failing on only one machine. I would also appreciate any suggestions as to how to either fix the problem or work around it.

Thank you very much!

JAB

Comment: What is the definition of BackEnd.Instance.Reconfigure();

Comment: There are a million possible reasons why this might be happening... we cannot guess what it is. The best thing that you can do is to add some sort of logging that will let you see what is *actually* happening in the code on that machine. Output a line of text for each line, or function in your code. When you check the log file output, you will then be able to determine exactly where in the code the problem is and proceed from there.

Comment: You leave detail out.  Does set get called?

Comment: Simulate a failure in UpdateConfiguration and see if you get the same symptoms in a control environment.

Comment: I can try adding some logging. I am unable to do that until the customer is done with the machine for the day. The set method does not appear to be called at all. The two symptoms I mentioned bear this out. @codeVillagerCU0 - The definition of BackEnd.Instance.Reconfigure() is irrelevant.

Comment: @Sheridan - A million possible reasons? Really? I would be happy to hear just one. That is, one reason why we have tested this functionality on at least 5 different machines successfully (including a clone of the failing machine) and the only place it fails is on the customer's machine.

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is not the only ComboBox that exhibits this behavior on the customer's machine. In fact, all of the ComboBoxes on the same tab behave the same way.

Comment: The definition of BackEnd.Instance.Reconfigure() is irrelevant if you remove that call and the problem continues.  Don't get on SO to provide possible reasons when have given basically no debug information.

Comment: ResetAll()... how does that work? I'm guessing it could be breaking bindings if you start setting collections and properties to new instances of their type.

Comment: The failing machine has a touch screen. I have no idea if that has anything to do with the problem. We have an exact clone of the failing machine in house and the application runs fine on it. Also, I have noticed other weird behavior. The GUI has 4 tabs. Only the 1 tab and (get this) half of the second tab are active. I can switch programmatically to any tab. Also, the last tab panel itself contains a tab control. The same behavior exists with this tab control. It only has 3 tabs, but only the first tab and half of the second tab are active. On this control, I can see this by mousing over...

Comment: If I mouse over the right half of the second tab, it does not glow blue. If I move the mouse over to the left half of the second tab, it glow and will respond to a click. Buttons do not seem to exhibit this behavior. In other words, we have buttons on the left and on the right side of the screen. They all respond to clicks. And like I said, this only happens on one machine. All other machines work as expected.

Comment: Although the default `Binding.Mode` is `Mode=TwoWay`. Set it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was the .NET version.

Our product does not use .NET 4.5, but we have been installing it. If you launch our application, it reports the .NET version as 4.0.30319.18408. Our application on the customer's machine reports 4.0.30319.17929. The difference was that the customer installed .NET 4.5 and we install .NET 4.5.1.

Installing .NET 4.5.1 fixes the problem.